# Java: What is the property of a JOptionPane object that prevents clicks below itself?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, joptionpane, jdialog

I have created my own JOptionPane using a JDialog, but I can't seem to replicate the behavior of a typical JOptionPane that disallows the user from clicking anywhere but the JOptionPane window.

What property of JOptionPane do I need to replicate with a JDialog so that I can mimic this behavior? (I am aware that JOptionPanes are simply specialized JDialogs, as you can see if look at the JOptionPane class source code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing more than a ***modal*** JDialog and it's the modality that gives it this property. You cannot replicate this directly without creating and using a modal JDialog as far as I know. You must be sure that the JDialog is set to refer to the correct parent window (often a JFrame) and that its ModalityType is set correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The Swing API to set the modality of a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) is one of the constructors with [Dialog.ModalityType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) as argument.

- [JDialog(Window owner, Dialog.ModalityType modalityType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29)
- [JDialog(Window owner, String title, Dialog.ModalityType modalityType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29)
- [JDialog(Window owner, String title, Dialog.ModalityType modalityType, GraphicsConfiguration gc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType,%20java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29)

To set the modality after creation: [java.awt.setModalityType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29)

To get the modality, use [java.awt.Dialog.getModalityType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#getModalityType%28%29)

The old fashion way is to use a boolean (other constructors).

Sometimes we want to exclude some Windows from the modality with [java.awt.setModalExclusionType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setModalExclusionType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalExclusionType%29) (rarely used)